# how check null pointer in c programming , get this compile error: used struct type value where scalar is required ,

Tags: c, pointers, null, structure

```
struct s_client *cur_client(void){
    return (struct s_client *) pthread_getspecific(getclient);
}



int32_t chk_process (int32_t) {
...
struct s_client *ptr = cur_client();

//FIXME
// how could i check in this line , just when the value of 
// ptr is not zero , then it goes to it's next line?`

send_data (ptr, index);
...
...
}
```

i would like to check , only at the time that the value of ptr , is not zero , it goes to it's next line , i tried this line of code

```
if (*ptr != 0)
```

but as  expected this wasn't correct , since it's not check the value !

Edit2 :
Well , i found myself the reason , since ptr fullfilled from pthread_getspecific . If pthread_getspecific is called on the key whose thread specific data is being destroyed, the value NULL is returned. For more info , u could check the man page ... End of the story

Edit1 :

Well This is the struct name cur_client() , which is use in above codes

Comment: Do you want to check whether pointer is null or value pointed by pointer is **0** ? And what is the error message ?

Comment: did you read any c tutorials?

Comment: the error compile message : 'Error , used struct type value where scalar is required

Comment: i want to check the value of the pointer (*ptr) not be zero  i am not intend to check the address of pointer ,  therefore if (ptr != NULL) is not what i want..

Answer (score 2):

You probably wanted to test if the pointer was not null. If so, you shouldn't dereference it when making the comparison:

```
if (ptr != 0)
```

Or:

```
if (ptr != NULL)
```

Comment: No I tried all of them , as said in my first comment , none of this not works , well the problem is i get segment fault error , this segment fault happens , since the value of ptr is zero (the adress of ptr is not zero , Therefore checking with 'if ptr != 0 or NULL , just check the adress of pointer and won't prevent this seg fault error , i would like check the value of the pointer not be zero to prevent segment fault .

Comment: @pooyair first, it's not a segment fault, it's a segmentation fault. Second, that segmentation fault is not caused by comparing the pointer to NULL. Even if the pointer itself is NULL, it can be compared. It just can't be dereferenced.

Answer (score 1):

`ptr` is a pointer to `struct s_client`, whereas `*ptr` is the `struct s_client` itself.

You're not comparing the pointer to 0, you're trying to compare the structure to 0, which can't be done.

Comment: yes , But it must be a way to check If the value of ptr won't be zero isn't , Well , i use gdb , and i set breakpoint , i saw , sometimes (in rare conditon) the segment fault happens just because the value of ptr is zero ,and currently i don't know , if that vaule be zero , how could i correct my source code to not call it's next line (i mean funtion send_data (ptr, index);) Any idea , is highly appreciated.

Comment: Just compare `ptr` with 0, what's the problem with that?

Comment: As told more than one time , if i check ptr with zero , it pass , And then i get Segment Fault , just because the value of ptr is zero

Comment: Sorry, it isn't clear what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to check whether the struct that is pointed to by the pointer contains zeroes only. You can do it like this:

```
int i, isNonzero = 0;
for (i = 0; i < sizeof(*ptr); i++) {
    if (((char *)ptr)[i] != 0) {
        isNonzero = 1;
        break;
    }
}
if (isNonzero) {
    /* etc. */
}
```

Edit: no, ptr is not the address of the pointer, it's the pointer itself. Compare it to NULL if you want to check that. A pointer is just a normal variable itself that holds an integer representing a memory address. A pointer-typed variable (which ptr is) has an address itself, which it seems you think gets compared when you use the != operator. No, it doesn't - you would have to write

```
if (&ptr != NULL) {
}
```

for doing that. Don't worry, other answers' suggestions are also good.

And please, make the effort to read a tutorial on C pointers. This is something too basic to be asked on StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks for reply , Well , before post this thread , i just google , can't succeed any helpful info like what u said ,  here is the Struct cur_client() codes                                   `  `struct s_client *cur_client(void){
`return (struct s_client *)           `pthread_getspecific(getclient);
    `}                                                                  Is there Any alternative way ie any availble Pthread Function that could do the same job Which u could Advice

Comment: @pooyair Please rephrase your question using correct English. I don't understand what you want.

Comment: No , what u said was not works for me , I have tried exactly what u said , but still i get segment fault because ptr value is zero and your checking codes not works!   , I also edit the  Thread starting post (first one) , The question is clear i think , and also i added the struct code (cur_client) , so now what is unclear for u, please let me know.

Comment: @pooyair are you explicitly setting the memory to zero when you're initializing it? Else it will be garbage and not zero...

Comment: if i got your meaning correctly , yes , i initialized it with     `pthread_mutex_init(&l->lock, NULL);`
Anyone could say any correct solution?

Comment: @pooyair what's `l->lock`? What's its relation to `ptr`? My solution is correct, you must have missed something.

Comment: Well , i found myself the reason , since ptr fullfilled from pthread_getspecific . If pthread_getspecific is called on the key whose thread specific data is being destroyed, the value NULL is returned. For more info , u could check the man page ...                       End of the story

Comment: @pooyair so why did you unaccept my question, once again?

Comment: "l" is mutex in the code , since u ask me about setting memory  , i told u how i did in the code ... the getclient key created properly before the pthread_getspecific... The problem was solved (segmentation prevented) by a hacky fix , which i have check the ptr for every milisecond not be zero by usleep , if anything else left u want to know , Please Tell me.     Best Regards.